# Issue when iterating a list in jsp

Tags: jsp, jstl

I have the following code in my jsp file:

```
    <c:set var="urls" value="<%LoginServlet.getAvailableUrlsConfig();%>" />
    <c:forEach var="url" items="${urls}">
        <c:out value="${url}"/>  
    </c:forEach>
```

`getAvailableUrlsConfig()` is a static method returning an array of Strings.

I don't understand why **it does not prints out anything.**..

If I use this:

```
<%out.println(LoginServlet.getAvailableUrlsConfig()); %>
```

it prints out the content of the list. Can you see any issues?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
<% pageContext.setAttribute("urls", LoginServlet.getAvailableUrlsConfig()); %>
<c:forEach var="url" items="${urls}">
    <c:out value="${url}"></c:out>
</c:forEach>
```

Seems that it does not like to use <% %> in jstl

Answer (score 0):

@Cristian I will not call myself an expert but some of my thoughts on your issue, ps. tried to add this as a comment but I need more chars!

I believe in your `c:set` you would need to have the syntax as an expression (than scriplet, this will not print anything since it's surrounded with a `<%..%>` tag.).

Expressions `<%=..%>` = With expressions the results of evaluating the expression are converted to a string and directly included within the output page. Here the `=` part indicates that it should print out the return value of the code inside the tag, whereas the scriptlets are statements. Note that when your using an expressions it does not require a semicolon.

IMHO I think if possible it is better to avoid scriplets/expression where possible, I would set any values on request/session or set them on page bean object. This way the jsps are clean and favours readability but of course depends on your particular issue/scenario.

You might find the following link useful as well http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/JSPIntro/contents.html & http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tutorial/1_3-fcs/doc/JSPIntro7.html

Hope this helps.